# python.net inconsistant automatic type conversion

Tags: .net, python, python.net

We are using python.net console embedded with our application. On a specific machine running the python console the automatic type conversion defaults to the base class of the object and not the actual type. On all the other test machine this works fine. The only difference I see is the version of the console( Python.NET 2.0.0.12 does not have the problem while Python.NET 2.0.0.16 does).

Does anybody have any clue as to what maybe going on.

Thanks